# Can I recover my old HDD?

Tags: encryption, password-recovery

HDD encryption!

Can I recover my old HDD?
it is encrypted, my user gets hurt and does not allow me to go beyond the desk, it connects and initiates session, but when wanting to do something it tells me insufficient space and sends a full HDD message and I can not do anything

Comment: Do you know the encryption key or password?

Comment: Yes, yes i remember my user password, the encryption does not remember it, I think I have it written down somewhere, and I remember now that I had another problem. A user sometimes did not want to log in.